# How to handle messages from recursive HTML UI in Elm?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, elm

I'm trying to build a UI that allows a user to manipulate a recursive data structure. For example, imagine a visual schema editor or database table editor in which you have plain old types (strings and integers) and compound types made up of those plain types (arrays, structs). In the example below, a `Struct_` is like a JavaScript object, where the keys are strings and the values are any type, including nested `Array_`s and `Struct_`s.

```
-- underscores appended to prevent confusion about native Elm types. These are custom to my application.
type ValueType
    = String_
    | Int_
    | Float_
    | Array_ ValueType
    | Struct_ (List (String, ValueType))

type alias Field =
    { id : Int
    , label : String
    , hint : String
    , hidden : Bool
    , valueType : ValueType
    }

type alias Schema = List Field
```

Now to go about building a UI for this I can make a simple recursive function:

```
viewField : Field -> Html Msg
viewField field =
    div []
    [ input [ type_ "text", value field.label ] []
    , viewValueType field.valueType
    ]

viewValueType : ValueType -> Html Msg
viewValueType valueType =
    let
        structField : (String, ValueType) -> Html Msg
        structField (key, subtype) =
            div []
                [ input [type_ "text", placeholder "Key", value key, onInput EditStructSubfieldKey] []
                , viewValueType subtype
                ]

        options : List(Html Msg)
        options = case valueType of
            String_ -> -- string ui
            Int_ -> -- int ui
            Float_ -> -- float ui
            Array_ subtype ->
                [ label [] [ text "subtype" ]
                , viewValueType subtype
                ]
            Struct_ fields ->
                [ label [] [ text "subfields" ]
                , List.map structField fields
                , button [ onClick AddStructSubfield ] [ text "Add subfield" ]
                ]
    in
    div [] options
```

My issue arises when trying to manipulate my state with this recursive structure. What data structure in a `Msg`s would accommodate user edits to this structure, adding new fields, subfields, and editing their properties? How would I properly decode that in my `update` loop?

For example...

```
type alias Model =
    { fields : List Field }

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        AddStructSubfield _???_ ->
            ({model | fields = ???}, Cmd.none)
        EditStructSubfieldKey _???_ ->
            ({model | fields = ???}, Cmd.none)
```

What kind of data would you attach to that `AddStructSubfield` or `EditStructSubfieldKey` message (that's passed with the `onClick` handler to the `button` above) to properly update your state, specifically when the `Struct_` is say, nested inside of another `Struct_`, nested inside of an `Array_`? `EditStructSubfieldKey`, for example, will only contain the new string that the user has entered, but not enough information to address a deeply-nested item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by passing an updater function down the recursive chain. I've simplified this example as much as possible while showing the recursive nature of the updating. This allows for updating infinitely nested structures and lists without worrying about encoding/decoding a path. The downside, I believe, is that my single update `Msg` will always replace the entire model. I'm not sure about the semantics of how this will affect Elm's equality checking, and if that will produce performance issues in certain applications.

This example can be copy/pasted into https://elm-lang.org/try as-is to see it in action.

```
import Html exposing (Html, div, input, ul, li, text, select, button, option)
import Html.Attributes exposing (value, type_, selected)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput, onClick)
import Browser

type ValueType
    = String_
    | Int_
    | Array_ ValueType
    | Struct_ (List Field)

type alias Field =
    { label : String
    , valueType : ValueType
    }

type alias Model = Field

main = Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }

init : Model
init =
    { label = "Root Field", valueType = String_ }

type Msg
    = UpdateField Field

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateField field ->
            field

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    let
        updater : Field -> Msg
        updater field =
            UpdateField field
    in
    div [] [ viewField updater model ]

viewField : (Field -> Msg) -> Field -> Html Msg
viewField updater field =
    let
        updateLabel : String -> Msg
        updateLabel newLabel =
            updater {field | label = newLabel}

        updateValueType : ValueType -> Msg
        updateValueType newValueType =
            updater {field | valueType = newValueType}
    in
    li []
    [ input [ type_ "text", value field.label, onInput updateLabel ] [ ]
    , viewTypeOptions updateValueType field.valueType
    ]

viewTypeOptions : (ValueType -> Msg) -> ValueType -> Html Msg
viewTypeOptions updater valueType =
    let
        typeOptions = case valueType of
            String_ ->
                div [] []
            Int_ ->
                div [] []
            Array_ subtype ->
                let
                    subUpdater : ValueType -> Msg
                    subUpdater newType =
                        updater <| Array_ newType
                in
                div [] [ div [] [ text "Subtype" ], viewTypeOptions subUpdater subtype ]
            Struct_ fields ->
                let
                    fieldAdder : Msg
                    fieldAdder =
                        updater <| Struct_ ({label = "", valueType = String_} :: fields)

                    fieldUpdater : Int -> Field -> Msg
                    fieldUpdater index newField =
                         updater <| Struct_ <| replaceInList index newField fields
                in
                div []
                  [ ul [] (List.indexedMap (\i -> (viewField <| fieldUpdater i)) fields)
                  , button [ onClick fieldAdder ] [ text "+ Add Field" ]
                  ]

        isArray t = case t of
            Array_ _ -> True
            _ -> False

        isStruct t = case t of
            Struct_ _ -> True
            _ -> False

        stringToType str = case str of
            "string" -> String_
            "int" -> Int_
            "array" -> Array_ String_
            "struct" -> Struct_ []
            _ -> String_

        changeType str =
            updater <| stringToType str

    in
    div []
    [ select [ onInput changeType ]
        [ option [ value "string", selected <| valueType == String_ ] [ text "String" ]
        , option [ value "int", selected <| valueType == Int_ ] [ text "Integer" ]
        , option [ value "array", selected <| isArray valueType ] [ text "Array" ]
        , option [ value "struct", selected <| isStruct valueType ] [ text "Struct" ]
        ]
    , typeOptions
    ]

replaceInList : Int -> a -> List a -> List a
replaceInList index item list =
    let
        head = List.take index list
        tail = List.drop (index+1) list
    in
    head ++ [ item ] ++ tail
```

Answer (score 2):

We do exactly this in our code base, but haven't open sourced the 'library' that supported this. But the answer to your question is that you need to add the notion of a `Path` to your code and messages.

```
type Path 
    = Field: String 
    | Index: Int
```

Then your view has to keep updating the path as you descend `[Field "f1", Index 3, ...]`, and your update function needs to be supported by insert, delete,... that take a Path and the existing structure and return you a new one.